# How do I do something like exec() with importing my variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do something like this for a project:

```
def printhi():
    print("Hi")
myinput = input() # for example printhi()
exec(myinput)
```

Now I get an error, because exec() just starts a new session and ignores my functions and variables. How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) builtin takes two additional arguments that can be used to pass in the local and global scope:

```
x = 10
exec("print(x)", globals(), locals()) # Prints "10"
```

Update: Given your example, I think a "better" solution (or at least something more realistic) is to not use exec. To call a function given by the user, try something like:

```
mypinput = input()
choices = {'printhi': printhi}
if myinput in choices:
    function = choices[myinput]
    function()
else:
    print("Unknown function", myinput)
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Also welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you, but that was only a simple example.
I'm coding a bot for the messenger Discord and I want to make an
Execute-Command like this.
*execute await bot.send_message(message.channel, "Hey, it's working: :D")
But then I have a Syntax error at bot

Comment: I don't recognize that syntax either. Is it `*execute await bot.send_message(...)`?

Comment: Maybe the message should be `'print("Hey, it's working")'` if you exec it?

Comment: Well it is a function of an object. It is from a discord API.

Comment: I doesn' look like Python though? Personally I need a little bit more context, maybe a longer snippet of your code and maybe a short explanation.